# Find binary number with max hamming distance wrt given set of binary numbers

Tags: algorithms, hamming-distance

Suppose we have a set $A$ of binary numbers with the same length $n$.
For example (with $n=8$):

$A = \{ 10010011, 01011011, 00010010, 11110001\}$

Now, I want to find the binary number $z$ (also with $n$ bits) such that the minimum hamming distance between $z$ and any of these numbers is maximized.

i.e. $z = \arg \max \{ d(x,A) \mid x \in X\}$

with

$d(x,A) := \min \{ d(x,a) \mid a \in A\}$

where $X$ is the set of all $n$-bit binary numbers, and $d(x,a)$ the hamming distance between $x$ and $a$.

Is there any efficient algorithm for this?

Obviously, if $n$ is small enough we can brute-force this, but I'm looking for something more efficient when $n$ is large. The size of $A$, on the other hand, can be assumed relatively small, so any algorithm polynomial in $|A|$ is fine. Also, it does not have to be an exact algorithm. Any algorithm that approximates the correct answer is welcome too.

Comment: If all your numbers are 8 bits long, you can just check all possibilities.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes, but see my update.

Comment: Start weeding out bits with one value, only (xxxFxTxx, in your example). Set bits with a clear minority value to that (xxtFtTff): probably, the values with maximal minimum Hamming distance end with 101100. Construct a counter example.

Comment: @greybeard: A counterexample: 10001 (and 01001, and 00101, and 00011) all have minimum distance 2 from $\{01111, 11101, 11011, 10111, 00000\}$ despite making two non-minority-digit choices, while 00000 (from always choosing the minority digit) has minimum distance 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the decision version of the problem, which we can the problem of farthest string.

> Given $m$ length-$n$ binary strings $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_m$ and a number $k$, determine whether there is a length-$n$ string $s$ such that $d(s,s_i)\ge k$ for all $i$.

There is the problem of [closest string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_string).

> Given $m$ length-$n$ binary strings $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_m$ and a number $k$, determine whether there is a length-$n$ string $s$ such that $d(s,s_i)\le k$ for all $i$.

#### Farthest string is dual to closest string.

Let $c$ denote the map that changes a binary string to its 1's complement, i.e., switching 0 and 1 everywhere. For example, $c(010010111)=101101000$. Note that $c\circ c = Id$.

Given an instance of farthest string $(m, n, s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_m, k, s)$, we can construct an instance of closest string $(m, n, c(s_1), c(s_2), \cdots, c(s_m), n-k, s)$. Call this transformation of instances $r$.

For every string $s$ of length $n$, $$d(s,s_i)+d(s, c(s_i))=n.$$
Hence 
$$d(s,s_i)\ge k\text{ for all }i\  \Longleftrightarrow\ d(s,c(s_i))\le n-k\text{ for all }i. $$

So $r$ converts a yes-instance of farthest string to a yes-instance of closest string. Symmetrically, $r$ converts a yes-instance of closest string to a yes-instance of furthest string. Furthermore, $r\circ r= Id$.

So $r$ is a linear duality reduction between farthest string and closest string.

#### All results about closest string are about farthest string.

That is because of the duality reduction. Now we can dive into [the Wikipedia article on closest string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_string) to see find what we have about closest string.

In particular, we know that farthest string is NP-complete. We can check [approximability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_string#Approximability), [fixed-parameter tractability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_string#Fixed-parameter_tractability) as well.